# Getting a dynamic filepath in vlookup for table_array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm doing a project for my company at the moment and was wondering how I can get the excel file name `Database.xlsx` in the example below dynamically? So that I can reference different workbooks.

```
=VLOOKUP([@[EIP number]]; 'C:\Users\nmichiels\Desktop\Corrective Action Management\[Database.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C1:R10000C5;5;FALSE)
```

Comment: You can construct a usable range address with INDIRECT but INDIRECT does not work on closed workbooks.

Comment: you would need to use INDIRECT, but INDIRECT requires the target workbook to be open.

Comment: So there is no way to do this with a closed workbook?